# Were the people on the bus transported to Tom Holland's universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-2, spider-man-no-way-home

In the scene below, Tobey's face is revealed, and thus he is revealed as Spider-Man.

Does this mean that (some of) the people on the train were transported to Earth-616? Therefore, weren't Dr. Strange and Peter incorrect to just look for people with special powers, as not everyone who knows Spider-Man is a villain...

Comment: I hate to say it - but there's no way to tell the limits of a made up spell - is seeing a face knowing someone, or even knowing who someone is?

Comment: As I recall, the people's comments were things like "He's just a kid!"  They didn't know who he was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

The spell specifically transported **anyone who knew that Peter Parker was Spider-Man** into Earth-616. The people on the train saw Peter's face, but did not learn his name, and none of them recognised him as being Peter Parker. Therefore, the spell would not have affected them.